# Found operand types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThanOrEqual'

Tags: azure, datetime, odata, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Getting an error while trying to get the entities from Azure Table on basis of **Timestamp** which is of type **Edm.DateTime**:

```
StorageError: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThanOrEqual'
```

[image]
Code:

```js
let res: IQueryPrePostAuthResponse[] = [];
let query = new TableQuery();
query = query.where('PartitionKey eq ?', searchQuery.user_id);

const entGen = TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
const dateFrom = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_from));
const dateTo = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_to));
query = query.and(
 'Timestamp >= ? and Timestamp <= ?',
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
);
```

As in code both variables(**dateFrom**, & **dateTo**) are of **DateTime** type and **Timestamp** is of DateTime type.
According to **Odata Docs** [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-comparison-operators) query comparison operator, The data types on both sides of a comparison operator must be compatible. Here is my case both are the same, been then I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

When filtering by a date field, do not put the date value in quotes.

eg. this is WRONG:

```
http://localhost:7048/XX/ODataV4/PostedSalesInvoice?Posting_Date&%24filter=Posting_Date+ge+'2023-01-01'&%24format=json
```

This is correct:

```
http://localhost:7048/XX/ODataV4/PostedSalesInvoice?Posting_Date&%24filter=Posting_Date+ge+2023-01-01&%24format=json
```

Also, I have an interesting JavaScript library for constructing `odata` URLs incase you're interested:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/navodata

Answer (score 0):

When I print **dateTo** and **dateFrom** before sending it to query.

```js
const entGen = TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
const dateFrom = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_from));
const dateTo = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_to));
console.log(dateFrom);
console.log(dateTo);
```

I got this in the output:-
[image]
After debugging a lot, I got to know that the way in which I was sending **dateFrom** and **dateTo** was not correct.

The correct way is **dateFrom._** and **dateTo._**. But this should be mentioned in Azure Table or OData Query but it was absent there.

*According to Odata Docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities) query comparison operator, **The data types on both sides of a comparison operator must be compatible**.*

This was creating confusion as getting error even the type of both are same. The correct code is below:-

```js
let res: IQueryPrePostAuthResponse[] = [];
let query = new TableQuery();
query = query.where('PartitionKey eq ?', searchQuery.user_id);

const entGen = TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
const dateFrom = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_from));
const dateTo = entGen.DateTime(new Date(searchQuery.date_to));
query = query.and(
 'Timestamp >= ? and Timestamp <= ?',
  dateFrom._,
  dateTo._,
);
```

Now I was able to query the entities from the Azure table on basis of **Timestamp** property.
[image]